# Can someone help me to read this seal (Characters identified: 江山如此多嬌)

Tags: character-identification, seal

Can someone help me to read this seal

[image]

---

Many thanks for your infos about this seal.
Here is the side carving, can you decipher it ?
Seems to be a date and  the name of the carver[image]

Comment: It is also the title of a painting:- Actually it is a favorite title for paintings of mountainous sceneries. More a descriptive title. [![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k9kw5.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k9kw5.jpg)

Comment: The side carving looks like 庚子 十二月 (December GenTzi year, it could be 2020, 1960, 1900 ....every 60 years) and the carver 吳朴 (name Wu Pu) 刻 (carved).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

江山如此多嬌, The country, the mountains and the rivers, are so overwhelmingly beautiful; 引無數英雄競折腰。It draws numberless heroes bow giving their curtsy.

[image]